# Json Array from spring Blank in the table using angularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, spring, rest, blank-line

i have json array from spring rest like this:

```
var v=[{"id":"A1",
"name":"Bobi",
"age":27,
"supervisor":{
              "id":"S1",
              "name":"Doni",
              "age":27,
              "supervisor":null
             }
},
{
"id":"B1",
"name":"Thomas",
"age":27,
"supervisor":{
              "id":"C1",
              "name":"Ronald",
              "age":27
              "supervisor":null
             }
},
"C1",
"S1"
]
```

i want to show it in the table using angularJS, but in 3rd and 4th row always blank.
How i can show "C1" and "S1" ?

Comment: What does table look like and where would these items go? Do you control api source? Better structure would help. What do those values align with in the other objects ...`id`?

Comment: You have different object structure, you should at least have something like: `{"id": "C1"},{"id": "S1"}`, probably you need to remap `v`.

Comment: i don't know how to remap with spring rest..

Answer (score 0):

Though your JSON is valid but C1 & S1 are not in the same format as A1 & B1.
So, if you want to show all values in the same table in same format, then the JSON should also have to be of the same format.

Having them in the same format in API is far much easier then formatting the JSON in angular and making it work like the other objects.

Hope this helps.